# Is it an acceptable practice to pass a file to service (and to get it back) through usual byte array?

Tags: web-services, wcf, service

I learn WCF. I have WCF service and WCF client. My service get a file, then edits it and returns it back. It works without any problems still. I pass a file to the service and get it back through the usual byte array:

```
/// <summary>
/// DWG file resaving.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="source">The byte array of the source DWG file.</param>
/// <param name="dwgVersion">DWG file target version (enum).</param>
/// <returns>The result (the byte array) of DWG file resaving.</returns>
[OperationContract]
byte[] SaveAs(byte[] source, DwgVersion dwgVersion);
```

Is it an acceptable practice to pass a file to service (and to get it back) through usual byte array or maybe it would be better to use some other container for a file passing at this case?

Comment: Is it a binary file?  What other container would you use for passing it?

Comment: Yes, it is a binary file. The implementation specified by me works without any problems still (on the local machine and in the domain network), but perhaps there are reefs about which I don't know yet. Perhaps, instead of using of an array of bytes some other approach is usualy used by other programmers. I asked about it just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or rather something like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITransferService
{
[OperationContract]
RemoteFileInfo DownloadFile(DownloadRequest request);

[OperationContract]
void UploadFile(RemoteFileInfo request); 
}

[MessageContract]
public class DownloadRequest
{
[MessageBodyMember]
public string FileName;
}

[MessageContract]
public class RemoteFileInfo : IDisposable
{
[MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
public string FileName;

[MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
public long Length;

[MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
public System.IO.Stream FileByteStream;

public void Dispose()
{ 
    if (FileByteStream != null)
    {
        FileByteStream.Close();
        FileByteStream = null;
    }
}   
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will read about `RemoteFileInfo`, `MessageContract`, `MessageBodyMember`, and `MessageHeader`.